# UIAutomation Tests timer wait until done

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, instruments, ui-automation

I use `UIAutomation` test and make script, and I need in cycle select `cell` in my `tableView` and wait until it download go to another.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Search"].tap();

for(i = 1; i < target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells().length; i++ )
{
    if(target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()[i].buttons()["Download"].isHidden)
    {
        UIALogger.logStart("HIDDEN");
        UIALogger.logPass();
    }
    else
    {
            target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()[i].buttons()["Download"].tap();
    }

}
```

How I can make it when download end I have another button name `View` and my `Download` is hidden. I have an alert with progress bar that shows downloading percent.

How I can stop  script and wait until it downloaded something and then go to another cell. and downloaded that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a while loop to check for the condition (e.g. alert with download progress is visible). Make sure you slow down polling for check in the while loop and also have a timeout.

Here is the sudo code:

```
while (target.frontMostApp().mainWindow()..<download_progress_alert>.isVisible()) {
    if (timeout) {
        <handle error>
        break;
    }

    //Slowdown polling
    UITarget.delay(<duration in seconds>);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why not? While loop will stop the test case progress until downloading progress alert is present. As soon as downloading alert goes away, testcase will come out of the while loop and you can click the next cell to start another download.